# RxJava .zip emits same values

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a code:

```
 val touchDownSource = BehaviorSubject.create<MotionEvent>()
    val touchUpSource = BehaviorSubject.create<MotionEvent>()
    RxView.touches(binding.containerOverlay)
      .subscribe({ me ->
        when (me.action) {
          MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> touchDownSource.onNext(me)
          MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> touchUpSource.onNext(me)
        }
      })

    val zipper = BiFunction<MotionEvent, MotionEvent, Pair<MotionEvent, MotionEvent>>({ v1, v2 -> v1 to v2 })
      Observable.zip(touchDownSource, touchUpSource , zipper)
      .filter { Math.abs(it.first.toPoint().length() - it.second.toPoint().length()) < 50 }
      .map { it.second.toPoint() }
      .subscribe({ Utils.toast(this, "${it.x}--${it.y}") }, ErrLogger::e)
```

I have 2 `BehaviourSubject`'s and emits to them `MotionEvent`'s - `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN`. Then I zip subjects to combine `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN`. But my `zipper` bifunction always take as arguments 2 same events - `ACTION_UP` with same hashcodes and coordinates.

What I do wrong?

Comment: `MotionEvents` are mutable - you shouldn't cache them. Indeed it states - `Values emitted by this observable are mutable and part of a shared object pool and thus are not safe to cache or delay reading`. You should start by mapping each value using `MotionEvent#obtain(MotionEvent)` or `MotionEvent#obtainNoHistory(MotionEvent)`. - this information is from the documentation on the method?

Comment: @MarkKeen your solution is right, you can make an answer under this question and I'll apply it

Comment: As I really only delved into the javadoc a little, although it solves your problem I don't think it warrants myself getting points.  Glad it's solved though! If you think it will help others you can always answer yourself.